# What to do with a Linux OS microSD image file?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, disk-image, embedded

I am trying to install Ubuntu on the Odroid U2 SoC (http://www.hardkernel.com/renewal_2011/products/prdt_info.php)

From this site I downloaded the "Micro-SD image file" (http://com.odroid.com/sigong/prev_forum/t2005-linaro-ubuntu-1211-for-odroid-u2.html)

I will admit that I'm lost and unsure what to do at this point. Do I transfer this file (ending in .img.xz) onto the MicroSD card, then just plug in the microSD to the Odroid? Or do I somehow "install" the image on the microSD then when the microSD is plugged into the Odroid the OS boots automatically?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't use that board but the logic is that, you need to extract the compressed image (.xz) by

```
unxz image_file.img.xz
```

The image file should contain all you need (Linux File system, Kernel, ....)

Then locate your SD card by `fdisk -l`. If you are using micro-sd adapter, then it could be linked as `/dev/mmcblk` or if you are using USB-SD converter, the device name might be linked as `/dev/sdb`. (if you see `sdb1` `sdb2`, etc., they refer the 1st partition, 2nd partition ...)

Make sure that the SD card (and any partition) is not mounted, you should use `umount -a` or `umount /dev/sdb1` (2/3 ... for the partitions), otherwise you may need to deal further problems

then you can load the image to the SD card by

```
dd if=imagefile.img of=/dev/sdb bs=4M conv=fsync
```

when the process finishes, you can eject the SD card and place it into the board. Then power the board.

Comment: `image_file.img.xz` doesn't look like a tar archive, just a single file compressed with xz. So a simple `unxz image_file.img.xz` should be enough to produce `image_file.img`.

Comment: liori, you are right. I amended the answer.

Comment: Outstanding answer. I wish the BeagleBoard folks would have provided the same at [BeagleBone Black | Flashing eMMC](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Flashing_eMMC). It would have saved me so much grief...

Comment: I suspect that they considered it to basic to list. It is easy to make mistakes like that when you are a product expert. (And not just in computers).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the actual best way.  In one step:

```
xz -dc yourthing.xz | dd of=/dev/sdX bs=4M
```

Make sure you get the right device for `/dev/sdX` (`fdisk -l`).

BONUS EDIT: To get output from `dd`, run this in another terminal:

```
while pkill -USR1 dd 2>/dev/null; do sleep 5; done
```

Comment: +1 for this being the correct answer. You can also use Ctrl+T on some terminal emulators to get the dd status without needing the extra command.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xz` to extract the .img file, then use `dd` to write it directly to the card.

Answer (score 1):

the right steps:

> xz -d nameofimage.img.xz
>
> fdisk -l (see which letter yours cd card has)
>
> umount dev/sdX (replace X with the letter)

A good step is always to clear your destination media first! `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4M`

> sudo dd if=nameofimage.img of=/dev/sdX bs=4M

`sync` (important)